Problem understanding the cup-products for the modified cohomology in David Harari's book "Galois Cohomology and Class Field Theory"
I'm recently reading the very beginning of David Harari's book Galois Cohomology and Class Field Theory, and I met a problem with the definition of cup-products for the modified cohomology.
Before introducing the cup-product of two modified cohomology groups, the author gives compatibility properties of the cup-products of two ordinary cohomology groups (pages 44-45):

After proving this result the author emphasizes (Remark 2.24) that this proposition actually characterises the cup-product in a unique way. Here I have no problem with it: for two given $G$-module $A,B$, consider the exact sequences
$$
0\to A\to I_G(A)\to I_G(A)/A\to 0\quad\text{and}\quad 0\to A\otimes B\to I_G(A)\otimes B\to (I_G(A)/A)\otimes B\to 0,
$$
where $I_G(A)$ is the induced module. If the cup-product between $H^p(G,I_G(A)/A)$ and $H^q(G,B)$ has been uniquely determined, then the cup-product between $H^{p+1}(G,A)$ and $H^q(G,B)$ is uniquely determined by the part (a) since the coboundary $\delta:H^p(G,I_G(A)/A)\to H^{p+1}(G,A)$ is surjective (and an isomorphism for $p>0$), allowing us to raise the degrees from $(p,q)$ to $(p+1,q)$. Similarly, the part (b) is used to raise the degrees from $(p,q)$ to $(p,q+1)$.
The cup-product of two modified cohomology groups is introduced not explicitly, but the unique bilinear map that satisties the analogous characterization:

Now I have problem understanding the uniqueness here (the author only says that "uniqueness follows from property (1) and Remark 2.24" without any further explanation). I agree that the degrees can be raised from $(p,q)$ to $(p+1,q)$ and $(p,q+1)$ with a similar proof, but how to lower the degrees from $(p,q)$ to $(p-1,q)$ and $(p,q-1)$? I know that the author intends to use the exact sequences
$$
0\to A_{-1}\to I_G(A)\to A\to 0\quad\text{and}\quad 0\to A_{-1}\otimes B\to I_G(A)\otimes B\to A\otimes B\to 0,
$$
but the problem is that even if the cup-product between $\hat{H}^p(G,A_{-1})$ and $\hat{H}^q(G,B)$ has been uniquely determined, we only get
$$
\delta(\alpha''\cup\beta)=\text{something in }\hat{H}^{p+q}(G,A_{-1}\otimes B),\quad\forall \alpha''\in\hat{H}^{p-1}(G,A),\quad \beta\in\hat{H}^q(G,B)
$$
which does not guarantee the uniqueness of $\alpha''\cup\beta$, because it seems that the coboundary $\delta:\hat{H}^{p+q-1}(G,A\otimes B)\to\hat{H}^{p+q}(G,A_{-1}\otimes B)$ in the long exact sequence induced by the short exact sequence involving $\cdot\otimes B$ does not need to be injective! In other words, we do not necessarily have
$$
\hat{H}^i(G,I_G(A)\otimes B)\overset{?}{=}0,\quad\forall i\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
So how could we manage to prove the uniqueness of cup-products for the modified cohomology, if I had understood well the author's intention?
Thanks for your help in advance.
Note. (a) In the whole chapter $G$ is supposed to be a finite group.
(b) The tensor product of two $G$-modules $A,B$ is defined to be the abelian group $A\otimes_\mathbb{Z}B$ equipped with the action $g\cdot(a\otimes b)=(g\cdot a)\otimes(g\cdot b)$.

The modern version of this is Theorem I.3.1 in the paper of Nikolaus and Scholze On topological cyclic homology arXiv:1707.01799

@D.-C.Cisinski Thanks for your recommendation! I will try to read this, but it seems that this paper is too advanced compared to my current level. :)

I'm not sure you should be linking to pirated copies of books!

@DaveBenson Sorry, I didn't know. I removed the link.

Another (nicer) way to get the product in Tate cohomology, from a pairing of (co-)chain complexes, appears in Definition 4.1.5 of
Hesselholt, Lars; Madsen, Ib
On the K-theory of local fields.
Ann. of Math. (2) 158 (2003), no. 1, 1–113.

Have a look at Theorem 4 in Section IV.7 (page 105) in the book "Algebraic Number Theory" edited by Cassels and Fröhlich.

Thanks to both of you for the references. I will look at them.

David Harari's reply: I must confess that I don't really understand what the objection of OP is: $I_G(A)$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb Z}[G] \otimes A$ (the group $G$ being finite), hence $I_G(A) \otimes B$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb Z}[G] \otimes (A \otimes B)$, so it is induced (or coinduced), and in particular cohomologically trivial. Did I miss something ?

@MikhailBorovoi I am very grateful for the author for responsing himself. I noticed this remark given in the book. But if I understood it well, the action of $G$ on $I_G(A)\cong\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes A$ is trivial on the factor $A$, so $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes A$ is not the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and $A$ as $G$-modules. I was very likely to be wrong and it seems that I need to think about it again.

@MikhailBorovoi I guess that $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_\mathbb{Z} A\cong I_G(A)$ as abelian groups via $\varphi\otimes a\mapsto (g\mapsto \varphi(g)a)$, so if we want this to be a $G$-module isomorphism we need that the action of $G$ on $A$ is trivial?

David Harari: It's a bit more complicated, because (as pointed out by the OP) we have to consider ${\Bbb Z}[G] \otimes B$ with action on both factors, and a priori (co)induced means that the action is only on the first factor. However, I suspect that the two corresponding $G$-modules are isomorphic (see for instance Remark 1.6. in my book).

David Harari: More precisely, if $A$ is a $G$-module, the $G$-module ${\Bbb Z}[G] \otimes A$ (with action on both factors) is isomorphic to $F(G,A)$ (functions from $G$ to $A$, with action $(g\cdot f)(g')=g\cdot f(g^{-1}g'))$ : indeed, the map that sends a function $f$ to $\sum_{g'}  g' \otimes f(g')$  is $G$-equivariant from  $F(G,A)$ to ${\Bbb Z}[G] \otimes A$.
But $F(G,A)$ is actually isomorphic as a $G$-module to the induced module $I_G(A)$; cf. Remark 1.6. in my book. So ${\Bbb Z}[G] \otimes A$ is induced, even with the $G$-action on both factors.

@MikhailBorovoi Thanks for the replies, I will think about that.
